# Would server traffic software (something like Piwik or Google) make a good case for using No SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics

We are trying to develop a company specific tracking software but not interested in Google or Piwik. Essentially we would have a JavaScript tracking code also. The data that it would capture, would that be best suited for traditional RDMS or can we get a NO SQL solution ?

Any thoughts or ideas welcome.

Comment: Kind of depends on what you want to "track"... care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating xml files could do the trick for a no sql solution but web analytics can encompass a very large ammount of data depending on your "tracking software."  You'll need some sort of relational data solution if you want to properly analyse the data and see trends such as how many unique visitors are using a specific browser.